# Modules ".module" file not being called when anonymous user

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I think I have a persmissions problem but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I've made a custom block in a module called "people_passed". When I'm logged in the block displays fine, when I'm logged out the block HTML displays but the CSS does not. I've figured out that this is because people_passed.module is not being called and so the CSS is not displayed.

Here is the contents of my people_passed.info:

```
name = People Passed
description = A block that shows how many people passed in the last year.
package = Other
core = 7.x
files[] = people_passed.module
```

Comment: How do you add the CSS? Make sure you use renderable arrays and #attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your module file defines a block, but isn't being parsed, then the block wouldn't work at all; you'd get all sorts of fatal errors, not missing CSS.

You've probably got page and block caching turned for anonymous users...that'll be why your exit code doesn't run. Try clearing the caches, it should make a difference.